Installing Tally prime 5 using wine
I am trying to install Tally prime using Wine on the latest version of Ubuntu, but I'm getting errors for winei386.
wine setup.exe
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32:i386"
Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file.
ShellExecuteEx failed: File not found.

pyare-mohan@fx505dy:~/Downloads$ ^C
pyare-mohan@fx505dy:~/Downloads$ apt-get install wine32:i386
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
pyare-mohan@fx505dy:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install wine32:i386
Fetched 247 MB in 51s (4,859 kB/s)                                                                                                 
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: info database format (2) is bogus or too new; try getting a newer dpkg
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

